# Topological Concrete Categories: Axiomatizations

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

I'm reading something on topological concrete categories. In every reference, given a category $\mathfrak{A}$ and an object $A$, it is assumed to be acquainted with the its structure (and in fact the objects of $A$ are said structured sets). Now, in a paper by Dikranjan, Giuli and Tozzi (Topological Categories and Closure Operators), the following definition of a topological concrete category is given:

"a category $\mathfrak{A}$ together with a forgetful functor $U: \mathfrak{A} \longrightarrow {\bf Set}$, such that the following conditions hold:

1. existence of initial lift;
2. fibre-smallness;
3. every set of cardinality $1$ has exactly one $\mathfrak{A}$-structure"

On the other hand, in the paper "Topological Categories" by Brummer, the definition of a topological concrete category is given as above, but replacing axiom 1) with existence and uniqueness of the lift, and replacing axiom 3) with the axiom

3') costant functions are lifted by $U$.

I expect that the two previous definitions of a topological concrete category are equivalent. I'm able to show that Brummer $\implies$ Dikranjan. In fact, if a set $X$ of cardinality $1$ has at least two structures, namely $(X,\mathcal{F})$ and $(X,\mathcal{G})$, then $1_X: (X,\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow (X,\mathcal{G})$ and $\overline{1}_X: (X,\mathcal{G}) \longrightarrow (X,\mathcal{F})$ are constant functions which agree by the uniqueness of initial lift.

Concerning the converse, if I have a constant function $c: X \longrightarrow Y$, I expect to factorize the corresponding $c: (X,\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow (Y,\mathcal{G})$ (for each $(X,\mathcal{F}),(Y,\mathcal{G})$) as $(X,\mathcal{F}) \longrightarrow (\{c_X\},\mathcal{F}_{c_X}) \longrightarrow (Y,\mathcal{G})$, where $\mathcal{F}_{c_X}$ is the only structure on $\{c_X\}$. However, I don't know if my argument is correct. Secondly, does the existence of the initial lift imply the uniqueness of such a lift, because of the universal property defining it?